# custom code for how to upload product image from backend to front end like ecommerce in php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.  I want to know how to be able to upload a product image from the back end to the front end of a static website using PHP.  Please help me.  Thank you in advance.

Select image :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
{ 
    $filepath = "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)) 
    {
        echo "<img src=".$filepath." height=400 width=300 />";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error !!";
    }
} 
?>
```

I have tried the code above. It is running, but the image is displaying only on the same page. However, I need the image to display on another page when I click on submit button.

Comment: Please don't spam code in the comment section. Format your post properly. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT pass the variable from a page to another until you use `Session` in PHP. **But that is not a good practice for product image.**

You should store your `$filepath` in the database and fetch it every where in your application when you need that.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect this page when image is uploaded;

```
header( 'Location:http://anypage.com/?filepath='.$file_path );
```

and you can use get method;

```
$filepath=$_GET['filepath']
echo "<img src=".$filepath." height=400 width=300 />";
```